# iOS Facebook SDK - Retrieve Friends Profile Pictures

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm using Facebook iOS SDK and I retrieved the user friends list.
Now I have each friend name and id.

I would like to retrieve the friend profile picture, is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this URL to fetch that picture

http://graph.facebook.com/IdOfTheUer/picture?type=normal

You can also use their user name like this:

For example

http://graph.facebook.com/facebook/picture?type=normal

http://graph.facebook.com/11239244970/picture?type=normal

Comment: Thank you but for some reason I receive a "blank" profile picture when trying to retrieve friends profile picture, not all of them...

Comment: Is there any sample/link for get uploaded pictures and videos in face-book sa well as in twitter?

Comment: Doesn't Facebook (the app on the phone and any calls we make to it) cache the image in which case seek times would be lesser if we call it rather than make a HTTP request directly. If the Facebook SDK does cache user's display pictures, how does one access it?

Answer (score 10):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath you get id of facebook user already.....am i right???
after that in just use bellow url to get profile pic through URLRequest....

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([friends count]!=0)
    {                        
        NSString *strurl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",[[friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strurl];///here you can retrive the image
        [cell setObjItem:url title:[[friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
        // Configure the cell.
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"<<<<<<<<<<------Array Null-------->>>>>>>");
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned before; Sometimes I retrieve a friend's profile picture as a "blank" picture, means the white person silhouette over the light blue background that Facebook provides as long as you didn't upload any profile picture

Comment: yes this url fetch pic of fbuser which display on facebook so if user not select profile pic and its skip blank then FB default pic with light blue background appear its a Default PIC By FB bt what u want??

Comment: Just a suggestion, your are allocating `strurl`, but not releasing it, consider to release that also. or just use `[NSString stringWithFormat]`

Answer (score 3):

```
 -(void)fbFriends {
        [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
    }
    -(void)fbFriendsInfo :(NSString *)profileid {
        [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:profileid andDelegate:self];
    }


    - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
        [self hideSpinner];

        lblGender.text = [result objectForKey:@"gender"];
        lblName.text = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
        self.idi = [result objectForKey:@"id"];

        NSString *first_name = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
        NSString *gender = [result objectForKey:@"gender"];
        NSString *last_name = [result objectForKey:@"last_name"];
        NSString *link = [result objectForKey:@"link"];
        NSString *name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *updated_time = [result objectForKey:@"updated_time"];

        NSLog(@"Profile Info : \n\n%@,\n%@,\n%@,\n%@,\n%@,\n%@,\n%@",first_name,gender,idi,last_name,link,name,updated_time);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:AlertName message:@"Facebook Done." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
```

Use Share Controller Class and call `fbFriends` So u will get friends id then call `fbFriendsInfo` it will return all info of your friend.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I do have the friend's id, the problem is when I try to retrieve the friend's profile pic sometimes I retrieve a "blank" profile picture although I should be able to access his profile picture