# How do I get my Facebook Friends' Pictures in a stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, image

How do I access facebook friends' recent pictures of my users on my facebook app?  I would like my users to see a recent feed of the pictures that their friends are posting on facebook (regardless if that user is tagged in the picture or not.

I have seen this in an android application and I wanted to program it for a website app.

Comment: [Have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245654/593709)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Android is tagged here but use the Facebook API

Comment: Good point but, I was referencing that on some Android phones they have this feature built in.  So this is really just an example of how the feature works to help clarify the question.

Comment: They use the Facebook API for Android